# Title Case for a sentence ending with parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to title case every sentence **ending with parentheses** containing uppercase letters only
NB: do not title case certain words such as "for, and, the" for instance.

So the original sentence is:

> **foundation for economic education (FEE)**

And it should be like that:

> **Foundation for Economic Education (FEE)**

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my "faulty" code, it capitalizes everything before the parenthesis...

```
(^[\p{L}\W]+)([(][\p{Lu}]{3,}[)]$)

\U\1\2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061123/4251338

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works fine for title casing the WHOLE sentence (except certain words ie "and, the"...) BUT how to apply it only for a sentence ending with parentheses?

Comment: You should clear out what is a sentence in your case : Does it ends with a period ? and new line ? Please provide more positive example and negative example.

Comment: What do you want your example sentence to look like afterwards?

Comment: The original sentence ends with a parenthese (so the code would be [)]$) and inside there are only uppercase letters.

=> So for instance, the original sentence is:
foundation for economic education (FEE)

=> And I would like it to be like that:
Foundation for Economic Education (FEE)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, so you're wanting to know how to only apply the casing to sentences matching a certain pattern, not do something special with the text in parenthesis?

Comment: That is not code, that is a regex and some escape sequences. While it might be tempting to cram all of the functionality into a single regex, it certainly is an unnecessarily difficult way to solve your problem.

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77226/725418

Comment: In short, read the [faq](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-capitalize-all-the-words-on-one-line). Apply `Text::Autoformat` to the string when you can match parentheses in the last word.

Comment: If `for` in `foundation for economic education` should stay uncapitalized (as is shown in the question and comments), this is not a duplicate of  [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-perl).

Comment: @RyszardCzech Yes, it is, you just didn't read the faq, like the answer said to do.

Comment: Is it in fact an R question? Why did you tag it with Perl?

Comment: Althussa, please clarify what programming environment this question is related to and if `autoformat($x, { case => 'highlight' })` indeed solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The regex that matches a string with no uppercase letters ending with `(...)` substring is, for example:

```perl
/^(\P{Lu}*)(?=\([^()]*\)$)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vbi3Tb/2). There are other ways, but this way makes it more convenient to build the replacement part, RHS, in Perl later.

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\P{Lu}*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than uppercase letters
- `(?=\([^()]*\)$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `(`, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` at the end of the string (`$`).

Then you may use the [`Lingua::EN::Titlecase`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Titlecase) like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Titlecase;

my $tc = Lingua::EN::Titlecase->new();
my $str = "foundation for economic education (FEE)";
say $str =~ s{^(\P{Lu}*)(?=\([^()]*\)$)}{ $tc->title($1) }re;
```

Output: `Foundation for Economic Education (FEE)`.

Comment: thanks for your help! Unfortunetaly for groupings, my regex flavor can only use the followings statements "\1", "\2", etc..., So in order to uppercase a letter, I add this "\1>". I can't use the "Lingua::EN::Titlecase" procedure...

Comment: @Althussa What programming language are you using? If it is not Perl, what is it? R?

Comment: @Althussa Please find some time to clarify what you are doing, in order to put the question to rights.

Comment: @Althussa Please let me know if your question is correctly answered or not, since if it is an unclear question (and it is now), I'd rather cast a delete vote rather than reopen.